# Error install Module LDAP odoo12 in windows server 2012 r2

Tags: python, ldap, pycharm, odoo-12

I'm Using Odoo12 on windows server 2012 with pycharm

i want to make connection with ldap authentification

i go to application search for ldap when i selected to install it

i get this error message

Erreur: 
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 1039, in get 
value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]] 
KeyError: 187

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 981, in **get** 
value = record.env.cache.get(record, self) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 1041, in get 
raise CacheMiss(record, field) 
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.module.module(187,).description_html', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception 
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception 
raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2]) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise 
raise value 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch 
result = self._call_function(**self.params) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function 
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper 
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call 
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in **call** 
return self.method(*args, **kw) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap 
response = f(*args, **kw) 
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 962, in call_kw 
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs) 
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw 
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 749, in call_kw 
return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi 
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2791, in read 
vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 5117, in **getitem** 
return self._fields[key].**get**(self, type(self)) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 985, in **get** 
self.determine_value(record) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1098, in determine_value 
self.compute_value(recs) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1052, in compute_value 
self._compute_value(records) 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1043, in _compute_value 
getattr(records, self.compute)() 
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 196, in _get_desc 
output = publish_string(source=module.description if not module.application and module.description else '', settings_overrides=overrides, writer=MyWriter()) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\core.py", line 414, in publish_string 
enable_exit_status=enable_exit_status) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\core.py", line 662, in publish_programmatically 
output = pub.publish(enable_exit_status=enable_exit_status) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\core.py", line 217, in publish 
self.settings) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\readers__init__.py", line 72, in read 
self.parse() 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\readers__init__.py", line 78, in parse 
self.parser.parse(self.input, document) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst__init__.py", line 172, in parse 
self.statemachine.run(inputlines, document, inliner=self.inliner) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 170, in run 
input_source=document['source']) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 239, in run 
context, state, transitions) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 460, in check_line 
return method(match, context, next_state) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 2726, in underline 
self.section(title, source, style, lineno - 1, messages) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 327, in section 
self.new_subsection(title, lineno, messages) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 395, in new_subsection 
node=section_node, match_titles=True) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 282, in nested_parse 
node=node, match_titles=match_titles) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 195, in run 
results = StateMachineWS.run(self, input_lines, input_offset) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 239, in run 
context, state, transitions) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 460, in check_line 
return method(match, context, next_state) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 2726, in underline 
self.section(title, source, style, lineno - 1, messages) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 327, in section 
self.new_subsection(title, lineno, messages) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 395, in new_subsection 
node=section_node, match_titles=True) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 282, in nested_parse 
node=node, match_titles=match_titles) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 195, in run 
results = StateMachineWS.run(self, input_lines, input_offset) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 239, in run 
context, state, transitions) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 460, in check_line 
return method(match, context, next_state) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 2675, in indent 
definitionlistitem, blank_finish = self.definition_list_item(context) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 2796, in definition_list_item 
self.nested_parse(indented, input_offset=line_offset, node=definition) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 282, in nested_parse 
node=node, match_titles=match_titles) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 195, in run 
results = StateMachineWS.run(self, input_lines, input_offset) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 239, in run 
context, state, transitions) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\statemachine.py", line 460, in check_line 
return method(match, context, next_state) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\parsers\rst\states.py", line 2371, in line 
line=self.state_machine.abs_line_number()) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\utils__init__.py", line 235, in severe 
return self.system_message(self.SEVERE_LEVEL, *args, **kwargs) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\docutils\utils__init__.py", line 193, in system_message 
raise SystemMessage(msg, level) 
docutils.utils.SystemMessage: :34: (SEVERE/4) Unexpected section title or transition.

---